# How to theme a button without glitching

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, uxtheme

I've been trying to theme a button in a Windows API application using C++.
I want to make the button label red at all times.
Currently I get *only a red label* until I move the window, after that I get *a button with a red label* as wanted. Sorry I'm not very experienced with the native Windows API (previously win32 API)

The code I've tried follows. I create the button

```
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
hButton = CreateWindowExW(
    0L, 
    L"BUTTON",
    L"Hello, World!!!", 
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_FLAT,
    rect.right / 2 - 100,
    rect.bottom / 2 - 25,
    200, 
    50, 
    hWnd, 
    NULL, 
    ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance,
    NULL);
```

Then to theme it I use the following code in the WM_PAINT procedure of the Window Proc

```
 case WM_PAINT:
    {
        // Use DrawThemeBackground

        RECT rc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        GetClientRect(hButton, &rc);

        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

        HTHEME theme = OpenThemeData(hWnd, L"button");

        if (theme)
        {
            // Setup a DrawThemeTextEx Options struct
            DTTOPTS opts = { 0 };
            opts.dwSize = sizeof(opts);
            opts.crText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
            opts.dwFlags = DTT_TEXTCOLOR | DTT_COMPOSITED;

            WCHAR caption[255];
            GetWindowText(hButton, caption, 255);

            DrawThemeTextEx(theme, hdc, BP_PUSHBUTTON, CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL,
                caption, -1, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE,
                &rc, &opts);
            CloseThemeData(theme);

        }
        else
        {
            // Draw the control without using visual styles.
        }

        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

        break;
    }
```

I wanted to ask if I'm doing something wrong or missing on something.
I'd really appreciate.

Comment: Do you need to call BeginPaint/EndPaint somewhere in that sequence within the WM_PAINT handler?

Comment: I've tried that but then I don't get any theming.

Comment: You seem to be trying to render the button control from the parent window's `WM_PAINT` handler. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Can I ask where to render themed controls? It almost works this way.

Comment: Either create an [owner-drawn control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/user-controls-intro#creating-owner-drawn-controls), or [subclass the control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/user-controls-intro#subclassing-the-window-class-of-an-existing-control), in case you need more control over its visual appearance.

Comment: [Custom draw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/custom-draw) is the easiest way to change the button's label color.

Comment: I just wanted to learn how to paint and theme the button without having to subclass the control.

Comment: If you do Owner-Drawn Controls, you can make it looks like you want. 
The subclass procedure can alter selected behaviors of the control by processing those messages that affect the selected behaviors. As far as I'm concerned, you need to subclass the control.